# How to distribute Varnish cache differently to different kind of requests?

Tags: cache, varnish

I have a redirect in my store that shows a different store view based on the client's location.
It reads the header via Fastly and redirects the customer to a different store view using every time the same URL.

When there are many customers accessing the store the cache is mixed, even with the redirect working the cache is distributed to all customers in any location, making customers from the UK see the US store view.

How could I customize the cache block via VCL file to not just redirect by distributing cache based on the location?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to hash the requests using that header, telling Varnish requests with differences in that header generates diferent responses.

Just add something like this to your vcl, replacing `X-Your-Location-Header` with your header's name:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  /* Custom header hashing */
  if ( req.http.X-Your-Location-Header ) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-UA-Device);
  }
```

See https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-built-in-subs.html#vcl-hash